# Escaping user input - before and after database entry?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Am I right in amusing that laravel + eloquent sanatises user input before adding to the database? So I don't have to do anything here?

I'm also wondering about escaping output from the database, I know how to do it:

```
{{{ $var }}}
```

But is it necessary? And if so, why? Is it to stop malicious user code being run on your site? But is not this handled by laravel when the data goes into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its two different types of "protection"

1. before inserting into DB its block sql-injection and things like this..
2. the three curly braces are for escaped or purified the data to prevent xss and so on.

see here:
http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures

Comment: yes because its use PDO parameter binding. so you dont have to worry about sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize on input, so no SQL-injections and stuff happens, this is a security measure(i believe).

And now you can do whatever you want on output, because now you have some data to work with.

Strip html(so no xss happens) and so on, it all depends how the data is going to be used.

Comment: Thanks but your answer doesnt really answer my laravel question